# SSIS storing logging variables in a derived column

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

### I am developing SSIS packages that consist of 2 main steps:

**Step 1**: Grab all sorts of data from existing legacy systems and dump them into a series of staging tables in my database.

**Step 2**: Move the data from my staging tables into a more relational set of tables that I'm using specifically for my project.

---

In step 1 I'm just doing a bulk `SELECT` and a bulk `INSERT`; however, in step 2 I'm doing row-by-row inserts into my tables using OLEDB Command tasks so that I can log very specific row-level activity of everything that's happening. Here is my general layout for step 2 processes.

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2468578/screenshots/step_1.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2468578/screenshots/step_1.png)

You'll notice 3 OLEDB tasks: 1 for the actual `INSERT`, and 2 for success/fail `INSERT`s into our logging table.

The main thing I'm logging is source table/id and destination table/id for each row that passes through this flow. I'm storing this stuff in variables and adding them to the data flow using a Derived Column so that I can easily map them to the query parameters of the stored procedures.

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2468578/screenshots/step_3.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2468578/screenshots/step_3.png)

I've decided to store these logging values in variables instead of hard-coding the values in the SqlCommand field on the task, because I'm pretty sure you CAN'T put variable expressions in that field (i.e. `exec storedproc @[User::VariableName],... ,... ,...`). So, this is the best solution I've found.

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2468578/screenshots/step_2.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2468578/screenshots/step_2.png)

Is this the best solution? Probably not.

Is it good performance wise to add 4 logging columns to a data flow that consists of 500,000 records? Probably not.

Can you think of a better way?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this...

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think calling an OLEDBCommand 500,000 times is going to be performant.

If you are already going to staging tables - load it all to a staging table and take it from there in T-SQL or even another dataflow (or to a raw file and then something else depending on your complete operation).  A Bulk insert is going to be hugely more efficient.

Comment: This solution calls for SSIS, so a pure T-SQL based approach won't work. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Phil Scholtes I'm not sure what else to say, calling an OLECDCommand 500,000 times is going to perform horribly.  You need to stream to a table for performance.  You can always add derived columns to hold your variables (typically we put the metadata in a batch table and then a batch id in the stream).

Answer (score 0):

to add to Cade's answer if you truly need the logging info on a row by row basis, your best best is to leverage the oledb destination and use one or both of the following transformations to add columns to the dataflow:

[Derived Column Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069.aspx)

[Audit Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141150.aspx)

This should be your best bet and should't add much overhead

Comment: Will either of these work for using custom fields like table name or message?

Comment: The derived column can be any field you want. you would simply map it to a matching column in your table